# PHP Variable Echo

Tags: php, variables, echo

I have placed some variables in and now tried to echo them.

```
echo $from;
echo $message;
echo $sent_timestamp;
```

The PHP page just loads and loads and then about after 10 seconds it goes blank.

I am just trying my hand at PHP so I am not that advance.
Any comments or suggestions would be very much welcome.

```
$error = NULL; 
if (isset($_POST['from'])) {
  $from = $_POST['from']; 
} else { 
  $error = 'The from variable was not set';  
}

/** * Get the SMS aka the message sent. */ 

if (isset($_POST['message'])) { 
  $message = $_POST['message']; 
} else { 
  $error = 'The message variable was not set'; 
} 

/** * Get the timestamp of the SMS */ 
if (isset($_POST['sent_timestamp'])) { 
  $sent_timestamp = $_POST['sent_timestamp']; 
}
```

Comment: could you show us which value did you set to those variables ?

Comment: More details please. Where are you running the code from? Your personal computer? a server hosted on the web? Are you defining the variables before trying to echo them..

Comment: @user, post that code in the question (edit it).

Comment: @Adelphia, it is a hosted server on the internet. Yes, I have defined the variables.

Comment: Check your error log.  It may have more details.

Comment: Please edit your post with this ;)

Comment: @BastienSander I have now edited the post :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your variables inside a conditional. The variables will only be defined if the correct condidtions are met. Try this instead.

```
$from = (isset($_POST['from'])) ? $_POST['from'] : "From var not set";
$message = (isset($_POST['message'])) ? $_POST['message'] : 'The message variable was not set';
$sent_timestamp = (isset($_POST['sent_timestamp'])) ? $_POST['sent_timestamp'] : "The time var was not set";
```

Using this method ensures that your variables are set no matter what.